# Yii2 : How to validate XSS (Cross Site Scripting) in form / model input?

Tags: validation, activerecord, yii, xss, yii2

Yii2 has support for XSS(cross-site-scripting ) validation of displayed data using the  helper class[\yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-htmlpurifier.html), however this only validates and cleans up output code like this

```
echo HtmlPurifier::process($html);
```

How to validate input for XSS of input such that this data is not stored in the database itself ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done using a [filterValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filtervalidator.html) by calling the process as named callable function of validation like this

```
class MytableModel extends ActiveRecord {
   ....
   public function rules(){
        $rules = [
           [['field1','field2'],'filter','filter'=>'\yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process']
        ];
        return array_merge(parent::rules(),$rules);
    }
   ....
}
```

Where field1, field2 etc are the inputs fields to be validated, the same applies for Form Model validations as well

Comment: Nice trick! Looked over that filter validator up to now. 
What I do regret about the html purifier is that you can't just ask it "would this text be safe"? I hate to store text in the db that had to be cleaned (indicating it could've contained malicious stuff). 
I'd much rather refuse it, but comparing content doesn't work as the purifier modifies the content always it seems.

Comment: true, if you need to reject text you can always use other validation libraries(check this comparison http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison) , it is possible to simply call any function in the filterValidator

Comment: How do you specify configuration options for HtmlPurifier in this case?

Comment: Like this I guess: `'filter' => function($html) {
    return \yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process($html, [
     'Attr.AllowedFrameTargets' => ['_blank'],
    ]);
   }`

Answer (score 0):

in the before validate method add the following:

```
public function beforeValidate()
{        
foreach (array_keys($this->getAttributes()) as $attr){
            if(!empty($this->$attr)){
                $this->$attr = \yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process($this->$attr);
            }
        }

 return parent::beforeValidate();// to keep parent validator available 
}
```

it will help you if you want to run Xss Validator before validate/save all attributes nested of adding the following line

> return array_merge(parent::rules(),$rules);

to every class extends the new active record

Comment: This way worse than using `rules()`  like in accepted answer.

Comment: @rob006 by this way you will not need to add array_merge to every class extends from the custom ActiveRecord, you just add it to the before validate method same result and same approach.

Comment: Nope. It is less flexible, less efficient and more tricky (you would expect such rules in `rules()`). You're processing all attributes, even if this is unnecessary (for example for integer fields), undesirable (like `content` which should accept JavaScript) or impossible (like array fields). This is "lazy" solution, which in long term will give you more harm than good.

Comment: but this way in case in the future someone added a filed and didn't, added the rules to it, the XSS issue will return, and for integers and date-time type fields we can ignore them.